# with token authentication method applied in django,I am not able to access fucntions with "POST" method

Tags: django

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def taskList(request):
      tasks = Task.objects.all().order_by('id')
       serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def taskCreate(request):
    serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid:
      serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
`
```

i have applied token authentication to my api in django rest framework in views.py..now when i send a url request in POSTMAN with the 'Authetication: Token dggjgsjgsjgfjggsdgggs' i am able to access GET methods but not POST or DELETE methods.like in this i can view my task list but cannot create a task since it has POST method.Everything works fine if i dont have token authentication applied
and also i am not able to access it from my browser after token authentication applied

Comment: show your code what have you done

Comment: added it to my post

Comment: can you share your urls.py? and what error do you get?

Comment: `urlpatterns = [
    path('task-list/', views.taskList, name='task-list'),


    path('task-detail/<str:pk>/', views.taskDetail, name='task-detail'),
    path('task-create/', views.taskCreate, name='task-create'),
    path('task-update/<str:pk>/', views.taskUpdate, name='task-update'),
    path('task-delete/<str:pk>/', views.taskDelete, name='task-delete'),
]`

Comment: i am getting an error of "AssertionError at /api/task-create/
You must call `.is_valid()` before calling `.save()`."..it not like i didnt check this..i even commented these in my code but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I used `.is_valid` instead of `.is_valid()`. It's a method, not a property! I've edited it to include the parenthesis, and now it's working fine.